# MySQL utf8_unicode_ci 利用時のソート順

Tags: mysql

以下の様なデータがtable:user入っていて
[name]
123456
１２３４５６
23456
２３４５６

SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY name COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ASC;
とした時に、
123456
１２３４５６
２３４５６
23456

になってしまいます。

こうなってしまう理由と、
以下の様にするには、どの様な方法がありますでしょうか。。

123456
１２３４５６
23456
２３４５６

ご存知の方、教えて頂けたら幸いです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

utf8_unicode_ci では半角数字と全角数字が等しいと解釈されるためです。

```
mysql> SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT '１２３'='123';
+-------------------+
| '１２３'='123'    |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
```

'23456' と '２３４５６' は等しいので順番は不定です。

たとえば utf8_unicode_ci で等しい場合に、さらに utf8_bin でソートすれば、順番を固定化できます。

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY name COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ASC, name COLLATE utf8_bin;
+--------------------+
| name               |
+--------------------+
| 123456             |
| １２３４５６       |
| 23456              |
| ２３４５６         |
+--------------------+
```